# Animate transform attribute in text svg

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

I have a simple code and want to animate element on svg element:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eo0fg20z/5/)

```
<svg style="height:200px;width:200px">
    <text 
        class="my-special-animation"
        ng-repeat="el in test.data | orderBy :'text':test.sort"
        ng-attr-transform="translate(0,{{el.number*20+50}})">
        index:{{$index}} - number:{{el.number}} - {{el.text}}
    </text>
</svg>
```

For the moment : I display the element when display value is true and position using number value in the object.

Is it possible to make CSS animation to translate the text to avoid blank line between values?

Another formulation of the question : how to animate the transform attribute with a start and end values ?

Comment: not able to get usecase... will there be 3 objects always in elements.data

Comment: I have update my demo and question to have a better usecase (I hope).

Comment: you need only to switch start and end values?

Comment: I would like have an animation like with d3js and transition [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/16h2bdnd/4/). You can have a transition between start position and end position.